# using 'useSelector' hook with typescript returns this error: Object is type unknown

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm using redux with typescript in my project. My redux initial state is :

```
const initailState={
    lots:[],
    isLoading:false,
    error:""
}
```

All I want to do is to see 'state.lots' when i use console.log in layout component but I see this error:

> 

Object is of type 'unknown'.

> 

Here is my store:

```
import { shoppingReducers } from "./shopping/shoppingReducer.tsx";
export let store=createStore(shoppingReducers)

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
```

And here is layout component:

```
const Layout = ({children}:{
  children:React.ReactNode
}) => {
const state=useSelector((state) => state.lots)
return (<>
{
console.log(state)
}
</>
```

And of course I didn't forget to privide store in app component:

```
import {store} from '../redux/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
  return(<>
 <Layout>
     
  <Component {...pageProps} />

  </Layout>
</>)
```

I tried to use another solution: Adding customize selector hook in hooks.ts:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState} from './redux/store'
```

Then I added this hook to layout components to use:

```
import { useAppSelector } from '../hooks';
const state=useAppSelector((state) => state.lots)
```

But I received the same error!

what shall I do now?

**Update:**
Here is the reducer :

```
interface LotsState {
    lots: string[];
    isLoading: boolean;
    error: string;
  }
export const initailState:LotsState={
    lots:[],
    isLoading:false,
    error:""
}

 export const shoppingReducers=(action:any,state:LotsState=initailState)=>{
       switch (action) {
        //  cases to fetch lots from api :
           case GetLotsRequest:
               return{...initailState,isLoading:true}
               break;
               case GetLotsSuccess:
                return{...initailState,lots:action.payload.lots,isLoading:false}
                break;
                case GetLotsFail:
                    return{...initailState,error:action.payload.error,isLoading:false}
                    break;
       
           default:
               return state
               break;
       }
}
```

And here is actions file:

```
export const GetLotsRequest=()=>{
    return {
         type:GET_LOTS_REQUEST
    }
}
export const GetLotsSuccess=(lots:Array<any>)=>{
    return {
         type:GET_LOTS_SUCCESS,
         payload:{lots:lots},
    }
}
export const GetLotsFail=(error:string)=>{
    return {
         type:GET_LOTS_FAIL,
         payload:{error:error}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's silly. But in my case the problem was .tsx suffix in importing :

```
import { shoppingReducers } from "./shopping/shoppingReducer.tsx";
```

I changed it to :

```
import { shoppingReducers } from "./shopping/shoppingReducer
```

and it worked! Of course shoppingReducer file is still have .tsx suffix, But I shouldn't write this when I import!

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a type for your Reducer. Because you haven't provided the reducer code in your example it is difficult to say if that is this is the cause, however such error would be thrown if the Reducer has not been typed.

E.g. the `state` parameter needs to have a type such as `LotsState`, which you can use as follows (the interface property types are made up just for this example):

```
interface LotsState {
  lots: string[];
  isLoading: boolean;
  error: string;
}

const initailState: LotsState = {
    lots: [],
    isLoading: false,
    error: "",
}

// Important for the state parameter to use the LotsState type
// The action parameter would also benefit from having a type, but its usability was not provided in your example, so I just have a mock type called LotsAction

export const LotsReducer = (state: LotsState = initailState, action: LotsAction = initialAction): LotsState => {
// reducer code here
```

Comment: Tnx. I tried your code but didn't worked for me. According to your advise I added reducer and action file to my question(last update). Can you read it again please?

Comment: state is the first parameter of the reducer, not the second

Comment: Ok I put state as first parameter. But I steel see the same error